# how to create a new database in oracle sql developer if hr database is still there?

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have already hr database in my Oracle sql. I want to make another database in Oracle sql developer and i also want hr database to be still present.
please suggest me how to solve this

Comment: What is the problem here? You cant make a database in sql developer. You can make a schema. By database did you mean schema?

Comment: yes i mean schema.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you come from an environment like Microsoft Access where you have many databases floating around. In Oracle you only have one database, which has (possibly) many "schemas". All the tables are part of one big database, but each table (and other objects) has only a (usually smaller) subset of users who are allowed access to it.

HR in Oracle is not a database, it is only a schema. Your database already has other schemas, for example sys.

To create a new schema, you actually create a new USER. (Probably for yourself - call it `dinesh`. You use the `create user` command, while logged in as sysdba. Then you log in as `dinesh` and start building your schema (create tables, etc.) You can use SQL Developer to copy tables from HR or from `scott` (another standard schema), or you can even "clone" (copy) an entire schema to your own. It would be best if you read the Oracle documentation for all of this.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/users_secure.htm#ADMQS007

Comment: how to create a new schema and then several tables under that schema?

Comment: @Dinesh - I explained that in my answer already. You create a new user, let's call it `dinesh`. (To do that, you must log in as sysdba.) You (as sysdba) must grant `dinesh` privileges - to create tables, to read from tables, etc. Then you log in as `dinesh` and create tables there, with the CREATE TABLE statement etc. That is the `dinesh` schema. HOWEVER, you CAN'T just go ahead and create a new schema, with tables etc., if you don't have the time or if you simply don't want to learn more about this stuff. (continued below)

Comment: Read about users/schemas, grants/privileges, and how you can use SQL Developer to do many of the tasks easily, or else you will be posting here again every 30 minutes during the process. This is what the documentation is for.